# Como converter números no formato float 64 bits para float 32 bits no php?

Tags: php, javascript, float

Em JavaScript eu poderia fazer assim:

```
  let settings = {

    valorFloat : file.getFloat64(38, false), //Le o dado da posição 38 no formato float 64 bits

  };

newFile.setFloat32(38, file.settings.valorFloat, true); //Insere o dado na posição 38 de newFile com o dado convertido para float de 32 bits
```

Como eu poderia fazer algo similar em PHP?   Ou seja, pegar um dado que está gravado em um arquivo no formato hexadecimal como float de 64 bits e converter este dado para ser gravado em um novo arquivo também em formato hexadecimal como float de 32 bits.
Um exemplo:

Ao ler o dado no arquivo que representa o decimal "0.39" temos a string abaixo com o número hexadecimal que representa o "0.39" no formato 64 bits:

```
 0x3fd8f5c28f5c28f6
```

Para este mesmo número real "0.39", a representação em hexadecimal no formato 32 bits fica assim:

```
0x3ec7ae14
```

Como se pode observar, não basta apenas desprezar os bits menos significativos para ter o mesmo número real com menor precisão.   É necessário efetuar um cálculo para fazer esta conversão, pelo que já pesquisei o PHP não tem uma função pronta que faça esta conversão, alguém sabe me informar como é feito este cálculo?   Daí eu mesmo conseguiria fazer a função para esta conversão.

Comment: No PHP você pode usar unpack() e pack() para converter números de/para formato binário (bytes) e interpretar estruturas binárias contidas em arquivos. O artigo https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/01/14/handling-binary-data-in-php-with-pack-and-unpack/ ilustra a leitura de um arquivo de imagem PNG.

Comment: Muito bom o artigo, uma pena que esta função suporta o formato float dependendo apenas da máquina, ela não permite especificar se vou trabalhar com 32 ou 64 bits. "g float (machine dependent size, little endian byte order)"

Comment: Me parece que o PHP 7.2 suporta ambos: float (32 bits) e double (64 bits) e em diversos endianess. Vide o manual de unpack() https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_unpack.asp

Comment: sim suporta ambos, mas todas opções para float e doble são "machine dependent", ou seja dependem da máquina que estão rodando, se 32 ou 64 bits.   Estou escovando os bits aqui, achei um material que explica sobre a composição dos números reais (expoente, mantissa, etc...) acho que vou conseguir resolver, depois faço um post do resultado aqui se der certo...